# Create a list of items that exceed a certain criteria with cumulative calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to create a list from this data set that shows item#, qty, and date needed. The main criteria would be the inventory quantity (column B) and I need the list to show what date the cumulative sum of each row exceeds that quantity in column B. The highlighted cells is the data I would like to have listed out with the date they correspond with in Row 1.

[image: Example of data table]

Comment: A single conditional format rule can highlight the first instance PLUS everything to the right. It's more complicated when needing to remove the highlighting after the first instance. Hmmmm.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office365 you could use:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:H$1,XMATCH(TRUE,SCAN(0,C2:H2,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))>=B2)),"enough inventory")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using two Conditional Format Rules. However, I was only able to accomplish this by inserting a blank column after Inventory. So, column C is a new blank column.

Select your data (D2:J5 in my case) and input these two conditional format rules:

```
=SUM($D2:D2)>$B2    --> (format as yellow fill)

=AND(SUM($D2:D2)>$B2,SUM(C2:$D2)>$B2)    --> (format as no fill)
```

The first rule will perform a cumulative sum and highlight the first instance plus everything to the right when the rule is triggered.

The second rule basically "unhighlights" everything to the right of the first instance.

You need to arrange the rules so that rule 2 runs first, as seen in the picture.

[image]

It's odd that it works this way, specifically arranging in that order, but it worked on my PC.

Comment: cool solution - you can improve it, e.g. omitting the extra column, by checking against the current column: `=AND(SUM($C2:C2) >= $B2,OR(COLUMN()=3,SUM(B2:$C2)<$B2))`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on my original post, I actually already have the conditional formatting working almost exactly like you described above but I am trying to have a separate list populated on another tab. I have hundreds of items that I am tracking so having a condensed list would be ideal.

Comment: Oooohhhh, I completely mis-read the question. Gotcha, ok.